# Order by Rand wp query

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

I used two wp query by rand from one category for two colums left (into two posts) and right (one post), sometimes coincides posts, how i can use one wp query by rand and add class for left colum for adding class flex-direction: colum ?

```
<div class="info__block__main d-flex">
    <div class="small__info__block">
        <div class="child__info__block d-flex">             
            <?php
            $project_cat = array(1,7,33,38,43,40,35,45);
            $select_post_1 = get_field('select_post_from_services_small');

            $args = array(
                'paged' => $paged,
                'cat' => $project_cat,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'post__in' => $select_post_1,
                'orderby'  => 'rand'
            );

            $query = new WP_Query($args);
            if($query->have_posts()) :
                while($query->have_posts()) :
                    $query->the_post();
                    get_template_part('parts/project', 'parts2');
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="big__info__block">
        <?php
        $project_cat = array(1,7,33,38,43,40,35,45);
        $select_post = get_field('select_post_from_services_big');

        $args = array(
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat' => $project_cat,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post__in' => $select_post,
            'orderby'  => 'rand'
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) :
                $query->the_post();
                get_template_part('parts/project', 'parts1');
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I try add count into loop, but result unsuccess, maybe i cant right clear code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nobody helps me, i fix this problem via this code ;)

```
        $i = 1;
        echo '<div class="c__block">';
        if($query->have_posts()) :
            while($query->have_posts()) :
                $query->the_post();
                if($i % 2 == 0) {echo '</div><div class="c__block_1">';}
                get_template_part('parts/project', 'parts2');
            $i++; endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
            wp_reset_query();
        endif;
```